# How to use volatile boolean to check whether the thread should run?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a class that extends threads as seen below, and I want it to have a volatile boolean field that it checks to decide whether to continue running or not. The shouldRun() method is called from the EDT of my GUI.

How do I get this thread to check the boolean to know whether it should run or wait() from my GUI's Event Dispatcher Thread?

```
public class RobotThread extends Thread{
    
    public volatile boolean run; 
    //if running == true, let thread run
    //if running == false, invoke wait() somehow;
    
    public RobotThread(AutoClicker autoClicker) {
        super(autoClicker);
        run = true;
    }
    
    public void setRun(boolean shouldRun) {
        this.run = shouldRun;
    }
    
    public boolean getRun() {
        return run;
    }
}
```

In general, I just want to be able to get this thread to wait() and restart from the Event Dispatcher Thread of my GUI with button. If there are any better ways to do this I'll be happy to hear it too.

Comment: How are you going to restart it from EDT? Is it user action or what? And what is EDT? For what your thread is waiting to be executed? Common way to deal with threads synchronization is to use synchronization objects. You can check for start this http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/synchronized.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the waiting and restarting I believe an infinit loop, `wait` and `notify` methods are what you're looking for. For instance, look at [this guide](https://www.programcreek.com/2009/02/notify-and-wait-example/).

Comment: Got it, thanks for pointing me to a resource!

Turns out I mixed up the order of the while loop and the synchronized statements in my code, which is why wait() and notify() kept on messing up and giving me illegalMontiterExceptions. Guess the problem wasn't really with my synchronicity.

 I guess I should delete this question then?

Comment: Good. Happy to help. Although, we're all make mistakes, so maybe someone else would need this post.